# Mysql Connector Types

Tags: c#, .net, mysql

How do you deal with the types Mysql Connector returns? It returns an object but I have to find out the type it returns before I can use it. I tried (int)reader["SUM(column)"] and it turned out that the sum was actually a Decimal so it caused an exception. It causes exceptions whenever I try going from an object to a type that it is not causing me to have to figure out each type before I can use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader has a method GetDataTypeName(int i), that implements [IDataRecord.GetDataTypeName(Int32)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0z0e0cyy), where 'i' is the zero based column index. The string values will correspond to the [MySqlDbType Enumeration](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-net-ref-mysqlclient.html#connector-net-ref-mysqlclient-mysqldbtype) member names.

If you have control over the database scripting the safest option is to specifically cast the Query or Procedure data type in the query.

Answer (score 1):

hey you are doing database development, you **got to know** each result type before you can use it in your code. It's absolutely normal to know beforehand what is the result of every query or stored procedure we call from .NET.

Comment: I know what the colums are but for things like COUNT(column) and SUM(column) how am I supposed to know what those return?

Comment: you know it because if you sum two decimal columns in the database the result is probably going to be a decimal. Or you can use a very defensive approach and do reader.GetFloat(... or cast to float in whatever way you prefer and this would probably fail less. But are you retrieving the sum in a column called "SUM(column)" !?

Comment: Actually SUM(column) is returning Decimal when the column is a UInt64. Does reader.Get<Type>() fail when the column is not that type?

Comment: I was thinking of this... surely summing up values of 1 type must be handled in a way that does not generate overflow so the result type is always big enough to host the result. Yes the Get<Type> would fail if you do not have an implicit conversion between the specified type and the actual type of the column. But probably you could use Decimals then and you should be kind of safe in most of the cases...

Comment: If it is not a Decimal it will throw an exception though. Trying to go from an object of any primitive type beside Decimal to Decimal causes an exception which is why not knowing the column type is frustrating.